# how to show the web view as OverviewMode(completely zoomed out) in android? how?

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview, android-webview

i want to load my web view as a overview mode(completely zoomed out). that is the webpage zoomed out completely at the initial state.

i coded like this:

```
webview_obj.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

its not working. what is the mistake and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just trying to figure that out myself. It seems that setting setUseWideViewPort in addition to setLoadWithOverviewMode fixes it.

```
webview_obj.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

This other question deals with the same thing.
[How to set the initial zoom/width for a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808532/how-to-set-the-initial-zoom-width-for-a-webview)

Comment: don't you have an issue with double-tap, which zooms in/out a view? I am just currently dealing with it.