# Webview image fit screen in Android

Tags: android, html, image, webview, screen

I load `a .jpg` in a `WebView`. My problem is that I found this: [Android WebView, Scaling Image to fit the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395292/android-webview-scaling-image-to-fit-the-screen)

and it doesn't work for me.

**Here is my code:**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width= display.getWidth();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+width, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    String html = "<html><head><title>Example</title><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width="+width+", initial-scale=0.65 \" /></head>";
    html+= "<body><img width=\""+width+"\"<img src=\""+"image.jpg"+"\" /></body></html>";

aboutText.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", html, "text/html","UTF-8" , null);
```

Comment: this is the right solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23656581/550393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are html image tag wrong check below code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= display.getWidth();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+width, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


String html = "<html><head><title>Example</title><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width="+width+", initial-scale=0.65 \" /></head>";
   html+= "<body><img width=\""+width+"\" src=\""+"image.jpg"+"\" /></body></html>";

aboutText.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", html, "text/html","UTF-8" , null);
```

your html string wrong formatted image tag like below code:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>Example</title><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width="+width+", initial-scale=0.65 \" /></head>";
html+= "<body><img width=\""+width+"\"<img src=\""+"image.jpg"+"\" /></body></html>";
```

formatted my code:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>Example</title><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width="+width+", initial-scale=0.65 \" /></head>";
html+= "<body><img width=\""+width+"\" src=\""+"image.jpg"+"\" /></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 5):

This wasn't working for me as i had high resolution phone.

Try this, it worked for me,
`webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);`

Answer (score 4):

You can style img tag before you load HTML into web view. Please see below code

```
WebView content = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String head = "<head> <style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width:   100%;}</style> <style>body {font-family: 'Roboto';  }</style></head>";

content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, head + post.getContent(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```