# Image is not fitted in webview's height

Tags: android, image, webview

I am using an `Activity` having theme `dialog`. In that `Activity's` layout I have a `WebView` and I am loading an Image into it. But image is exceeding the height not fit properly. But I want to fit the image's height as WebView's height. I am sharing my code snippet and please tell me how can I overcome this problem.

Code snippet of `Activity`

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0 * 00000000);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
myWebView.loadUrl(image1);
myWebView.refreshDrawableState();
```

I am giving full Xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CC000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.56" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".27"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="50sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/load" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel_lay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".55"
                android:background="@drawable/load"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/load"
                    android:fadingEdge="none"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:alpha=".9"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50sp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="#dedcdc" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1.7" >

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/play_icon" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                                android:gravity="right" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_start_time"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:text="00.00"
                                    android:textColor="#000"
                                    android:textSize="13sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1.2" >

                                <SeekBar
                                    android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:padding="10dip"
                                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
                                    android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1.8" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_end_time"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:text="00.00"
                                    android:textColor="#000"
                                    android:textSize="13sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.6"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:fadingEdge="none"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:overScrollMode="never" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                        <com.creepster.LinkEnabledTextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_caption"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                            android:paddingRight="10sp"
                            android:paddingTop="8sp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.51"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_home"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/home_black_bg"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/search"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/srcollimage"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_love"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/activity"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_me"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/me"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I hope this will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395292/android-webview-scaling-image-to-fit-the-screen

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu I have tried all those solution but haven't work for me anyway ty