# WebView is failing to load some webpages

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I getting the below error when trying to load some webpages

> Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Please add your code snippets to elaborate your question, as this will help to identify the issue.
Are you loading webpages using webview.loadUrl() method ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by implementing the below code:

```
webView_courseLesson.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView_courseLesson.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView_courseLesson.settings.useWideViewPort = true
```

By default the javaScript support is turned off by the Android framework. Though you can check documentation here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/security.html

Comment: "Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' blablabla", when you look in the page source code there is indeed a ";" in the meta tag. because of this the webview is blank.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using webview.loadUrl() method to load a web page make sure that elements in the **content** attribute in **meta** tag (of web page's html) should have its elements comma "," separated neither semi-colon ";" nor blank space, for example:

**Like this:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3"> //best practice
```

**Not even this, though supported but not recommended:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3">
```

**Not even this, though supported but not recommended:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3">
```

So, see **meta** tag in your html's **head** tag having **name="viewport"**, it should have it elements (i.e. key=values) comma separated in its **content** attribute, so after fixing it should like this:

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
....
</head>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Also see this similar thread: [Android Webview - Scale image to fit screen properly with one loadUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000646/android-webview-scale-image-to-fit-screen-properly-with-one-loadurl)

Comment: I have the same scenario but the website is not my website and cannot change its source code. How to handle in that case? Most mobile browser loads without a problem.