# How to fit web images to Android screen size inside a WebView? while getting content of a site using JSON data, using restful

Tags: android, json, image, rest, retrofit

I'm fetching Json data using Rest API. And showing the contents in a WebView only, but that web images are showing in it's full size there. I want to make the images fit to the screen size.

Below is my code:

```
    content = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.content);
    final WebViewLoader webViewLoader = new WebViewLoader(content);
    webViewLoader.setWebSettings();

    String url = Const.get_content_by_id.replace("POST_ID",String.valueOf(id));

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            try {
                JSONObject ParentObject = new JSONObject(s);
                webViewLoader.setLoadDataWithBaseUrl(ParentObject.getJSONObject("content").getString("rendered"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            Toast.makeText(Post.this,"Unable to Load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

SingletonVolley.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: where are you trying to show images, in an ImageView or inside WebView along with other web contents?

Comment: I'm showing content of a wp site on a webview, that content contains some image. The images are showing in large size as their sizes are large.. while the writings are formatted like responsive..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView, Scaling Image to fit the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395292/android-webview-scaling-image-to-fit-the-screen)

Comment: No. this is not duplicate of above  question . He is populating web view with url.

Comment: Populating webview is not the concern here, webview can be populated in multiple ways. The concern here is how to fit webview contents into device screen size, that's why I believe you can be benefitted from that question.

Comment: Yes saw that post before and that didn't solved my problem.

Comment: did you tried adding `viewport` meta tag into your webview content? from the code you attached it seems so similar with loading content from URL, because from the JSON response you are ultimately parsed a URL that is loaded finally. you are not loading any direct JSON data into the webview.

Comment: Thanks It's solved.No, didn't add viewport

Comment: cool, then share the solution here by posting a answer so that others can use too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved it by setting the **style** tag with the web content.

```
webViewLoader.setLoadDataWithBaseUrl("<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%</style>"+ParentObject.getJSONObject("content").getString("rendered"));
```

If someone wants to add any more style just add `<style></style>` after or before `<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso Image Rendering and Caching Library and use its method to customize the images.

```
 ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(ctx)
                .load(res)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .resize(Main_page.getScreenWidth(ctx),Main_page.getScreenHeight(ctx))
                .centerInside()
                .into(img);
```

Also get the screenwidth and screenHeight to resize the image to screen size and then use centerInside() to make the picture fit in the webview.

You can get screen width and height like this.

```
    public static  int getScreenWidth(Context c) {
      WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
      Display display = null;
      if (wm != null) {
        display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
      }
      Point size = new Point();
      if (display != null) {
        display.getSize(size);
      }
      return size.x;
    }
    public static  int getScreenHeight(Context c) {
      WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
      Display display = null;
      if (wm != null) {
        display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
      }
      Point size = new Point();
      if (display != null) {
        display.getSize(size);
      }
      return size.y;
   }
```

For webview use below code:

```
   WebView img = findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        img.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        img.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        img.loadUrl(res);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.zoominwithoutnet);
        getWindow()
                .setLayout(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                );
```

Comment: he is not using any ImageView, rather showing that web images into a WebView. So Picasso library is not the appropriate solution for this issue.