# Webview app has too much width

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, width

I have made an android app with webview, but the width is more than the phone.
I want to have the website fullscreen, so you must not scroll left/right.

I can't see the whole page. How is this possible?

Preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlq6D.png

Who can help me?

Comment: You should post the XML file of the layout (or the relevant code if you didn't use an XML file).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

see [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort%28boolean%29)

> Tells the WebView to use a wide viewport. The default is false.

Comment: Try this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808532/how-to-set-the-initial-zoom-width-for-a-webview)