# Fit Webview content to screen

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I've a webview that loads a website from local assets folder:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    //webView.setInitialScale(1);
    //webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    //webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    if ((Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()).contains("ar"))
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Index-ar.html");
    else
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Index-en.html");
```

By default, the webpage is zoomed in and the user have to scroll and all what I want is to fit the page width to the webview width (which is full screen).

The comments shows you what I've tried:

`setInitialScale(1)` hides all the content of the page!

`setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR)` changes nothing.

`setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` and `setUseWideViewPort(true)` zooms out to much.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you tried this :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322209/1155805 ??

Comment: Still it's zoomed out

Answer (score 9):

Its little late, but it can help some who needs it.

Add following in head tag of the webpage :

```
<meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,text/html,charset=utf-8' >
```

Then add this in activity :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setInitialScale(1);

webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

If you want to support zoom buttons you can add this –

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try this :

```
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: It zooms out too much just like when I used the last two lines of your code

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to do that by xml? Set layout width and height to fill_parent.

```
<WebView  
      android:id="@+id/webView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: I'm using that now. My webview fills the screen with match_parent for width and height. But the issue is on the content of the webview not fitting themselves to the width and height of the webview.