# eBay oauth token flow on small screen i.e. smartphone

Tags: oauth, token, registration, ebay-api

I've been struggling for couple of days with eBay token authentication on smartphones. I am able to register customer tokens on desktop systems, tablets and hires smartphones. On the android app there is a intent listener to get the reply and register the token within the app.

But on some devices, the following message occurs within registration flow trough ebay:

This can not be done on a small screen. Please try again with a desktop computer.

eBay customer support told me, that it is not possible to use the registration on apps. But i don't understand this, because the registration window for the token registration flow is matching even on small devices!

Any idea to solve this? Eventually to simulate a higher resolution / meta information for the web-view so the message wouldn't generated from the eBay server?

Thank you very much for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had to zoom out the browser window

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322209/1849478

also needed to set the UserAgent of the Webview like this:

```
String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.1";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(agent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the browser size with javascript.

```
<html>
 <head>
<script>
  window.alert("Window resolution before overwrite is " + window.screen.availWidth + " x " + window.screen.availHeight);
  Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "availWidth", { get: function(){return 0; }});
  Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "availHeight", { get: function(){return 0; }});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  window.alert("Window resolution after overwrite is " + window.screen.availWidth + " x " + window.screen.availHeight);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is another way](https://github.com/atesgoral/browsersize.com/blob/gh-pages/index.html)